# Capacitor electromagnetic radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance

The plate capacitor is charged and discharged with sinusoidally changing electric current. Why does a capacitor emit electromagnetic radiation?

Answer (score 1):

A charged particle possesses an electric field and a moving charged particle produces as magnetic field. Charging (and also discharging) the capacitor sinusoidally accelerates the charged particles with a certain frequency $\nu$. This leads to emission of electro-magnetic radiation of energy $E = h \nu$, as the produced magnetic and electric fields caused by the charged particle vary over time. An electro-magnetic wave is nothing else than a temporal and spatial variation of electric and magnetic fields.

For further reads see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259287/electric-field-around-a-moving-charge), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108744/acceleration-of-electric-charges-and-radiation) and [here](http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m6/production_of_em_waves.html)
.

Answer (score 0):

What we define radiation is a component of the EM field caused by an accelerating charge.

For a capacitor discharging sinusoidally

$\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t} ≠ 0$

Meaning there is radiation.

See: [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko's_equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations)