Lorentz force error in the present 2024 version of the gravitoelectromagnetism Wikipedia page?
I noticed that the Gravitoelectromagnetism (GEM) Wikipedia page has been edited recently. The factor of 4 in the GEM Lorentz force equation is now missing. But the GEM field equations are identical to Maxwell's equations except for a change of sign and rescaling. Having read other articles here, my understanding is that, given this form of the field equations, the factor of 4 should be present in the GEM Lorentz force equation. Has someone edited the Wikipedia page and introduced an error by leaving the field equations unchanged while omitting the factor of 4 from the force equation?

The Wikipedia page is definitely wrong as it stands. You can move factors of $2$ around, but you definitely can't pretend none of them exist. This is unfortunately another example of why I would never trust Wikipedia for sensitive details like sign factors and $2$'s.

The edit was made with the comment "Mashoon's paper contains a calculation error in eq. 1.4 which places a factor 4/c instead of 1/c in front of A." I don't know whether it's correct. The same editor then made this edit.

I hadn't noticed that the same editor made another edit on scaling. The new text says "Some of these scaling choices will not allows all the GEM and EM equations to be perfectly analogous." The use of the word "some" contradicts the discussion at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413056/ which states that the factor can be moved around but can't be made to disappear.

I’m voting to close this question (v3) because it seems to be a discussion for Wikipedia and its Talk pages rather than Phys.SE. Moreover, the physics issue itself seems to be a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413056/2451
